# Speed-up execution of multiple async/await calls

Tags: javascript, node.js, performance, parallel-processing, async-await

I can't share my exact code - but I have tried to illustrate my situation below:

The remote API has a request max. limit of 10 requests/pér sec. and I would like to speed up my code to come close to this limit. Currently the code is running 1-2 request per sec.

Example - Fetch 10 hours of data for 100 different persons:

```
(async function get(...) {
    await getPersonData(for one person);
    if (not all persons' data has been fetched) { get(fetch data for the next person); }
})(...);

async function getPersonData() {
    const personData = await getHistoricalData(...);
    ...
};

async function getHistoricalData(...) {

    // Fetch 10 hours of data ...

    while (as long as all data has not yet been fetch...) {
        const data = await getOneHourOfData(...);
        ...
    }
    return all_20_hours_of_data;
} 

async function getOneHourOfData(...) {
    return await remote.api.getData(get 1 hour of data);
}
```

The example above is my standard version of my code - I have tried two different approaches as well:

- to use Promise.all() and fetch like 5 persons' simultaneously
- to copy/paste and run multiple version of the get() function simultaneously (the first 4 lines code block)

both methods worked - but none of them seem to speed-up anything...??
I have an idea that it is the while-loop which block/slow down the entire process?

Comment: Both of the things you've said you've tried should work, suggesting there was a problem implementing those ideas. We can't help you with code we can't see. :-) Please show us the code you tried to use for those. Please post **real** code, not pseudocode, ideally runnable via [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/). It doesn't have to be your real code of course, and you'll want to emulate the `remote.api.getData` with a `setTimeout`, but making it real code removes ambiguity and helps us help you.

Comment: I fully understand. But due to the fact that I managed to make all the code examples to work - but they didn't speed up the entire process ..then I thought that a psydo-code/concept would do it. But alright - I will try to come up with something more concrete if I don't make any obvious error in the example above :)

Comment: We can always offer better answers if we see the real code and the main benefit to you is that we can even offer suggestions/improvements you didn't even think of to ask for.  For some unknown reason, people posting here think they should ask a generic question with pseudo-code - that is almost never the best option for you.  Please always show the relevant real code and we can help you more accurately and with actual code you can use and can help you in ways you didn't even know to ask.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code in your question looks effectively like this:

```js
(async function get() {
    try {
        console.time("get");
        console.log(JSON.stringify(await getPersonData()));
        console.timeEnd("get");
    } catch (e) {
        console.error(e);
    }
})();

async function getPersonData() {
    const personData = await getHistoricalData();
    return personData;
};

async function getHistoricalData() {
    const data = [];
    for (let hour = 0; hour < 10; ++hour) {
        data.push(await getOneHourOfData());
    }
    return data;
} 

function delay(ms) {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}

let num = 0;
async function getOneHourOfData() {
    await delay(150);
    return ++num;
}
```

It takes about 1500ms to run.

Here's the same thing doing the 10 "hours" calls in parallel and using `Promise.all`:

```js
(async function get() {
    try {
        console.time("get");
        console.log(JSON.stringify(await getPersonData()));
        console.timeEnd("get");
    } catch (e) {
        console.error(e);
    }
})();

async function getPersonData() {
    const personData = await getHistoricalData();
    return personData;
};

async function getHistoricalData() {
    const promises = [];
    for (let hour = 0; hour < 10; ++hour) {
        promises.push(getOneHourOfData()); // <== No `await`!
    }
    return Promise.all(promises); // <== `await `on this line is optional but
                                  // pointless, this is an `async`
                                  // function, so its promise will be
                                  // resolved to the promise we return
} 

function delay(ms) {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}

let num = 0;
async function getOneHourOfData() {
    await delay(150);
    return ++num;
}
```

It runs in about 150ms, because the 10 calls for historical data happen in parallel. Note that the key thing is to build up an array of promises (without `await`ing them), then use `Promise.all` to get a single promise for that entire array of promises.

Comment: aahh! When I tried to use Promise.all() I didn't do it on the getOneHourOfData function - but on the get() function ...I guess - that must be the reason for it to work - but without any speed improvements! Thank you so much my friend! I will try it out and return to you asap! :) thank you again! Btw - do you personally use Promise.all(all your life's tasks in a day) ...otherwise how do you get time to get 147 gold badges!? LOL! Impressive!

Comment: @PabloDK - LOL! It would work if you did it in `get`, too, but the key thing is to build up the array of promises without awaiting them, then `await` the result of `Promise.all`. Happy coding!

Comment: I realized earlier today that the API client I use has a built in max-rate-limit which added a pause of 500ms between each API call! So no wonder I couldn't get my code to run fast! lol! The remote API allow 20 calls pér/secs - what is the best way / best practice to control this? Currently I have set the built-in rate-limit to pause for 50ms after each call (1000ms/50ms = 20 call/secs)...I then start and execute 50 simultaneously fetching promises and promise.all(all 50) before I load the next 50... it seems to work...But I guess it can still be improved?

Comment: @PabloDK - Sounds reasonable to me. :-)

Comment: Okay then :-) and you would not add some kind of extra layer to control this flow? May be via some swift NPM module or similar? :-)

Comment: @PabloDK - I don't know of a specific npm package that would do it, but yeah, I might do a rate-limiting wrapper for `axios` or some such. But if it's just this one API, that might be overkill unless you're using it in lots of places.

Comment: I have just finished reading the entire DOCS of this NPM module (it seems pretty solid and just what I had in mind): https://www.npmjs.com/package/bottleneck. I don't feel 100% safe with the built-in rate-limit in my current API client (I can still exceed the actual rate-limit (and receive error 429 from the remote API) - it doesn't seem to take overload/a lot of simultaneous calls into consideration). I prefer to use a dedicated module for this instead - which concept includes queuing, atomic execution and max simultaneously calls :-D

Answer (score 1):

You could use a (very special) Semaphore to limit the API calls to a certain rate:

```
 class TimeSemaphore {
   #times = []; 
   #backlog = Promise.resolve();

   constructor(interval, parallel) {
     this.interval = interval; this.parallel = parallel;
   }

   async aquire(cb) {
     this.#backlog = this.#backlog.then(() => {
      if(this.#times.length >= this.parallel && Date.now() - this.#times[0] < this.interval)
         return new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, this.interval - (Date.now() - this.#times[0]));
     });

    this.#times.push(Date.now());

    await this.#backlog;

    try {
      return await cb();
    } finally {
      this.#times.shift();
    }
  }
 }
```

This can be used as:

```
  const apiLimit = new TimeSemaphore(1000, 5);

  async function callAPI() {
    await apiLimit.aquire(async function() {
      await fetch(...);
     });
  }

  callAPI(); // as often as you want
```

Comment: It looks fancy - could you please elaborate what the code does and how...it is not clear to me :-)

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to use `Promise.all`.

```js
const data = await Promise.all([
  getOneHourOfData(params)
  ... // the same as above but different params x times
])
```

Now, i am very curious about `while (as long as all data has not yet been fetch...) {` expression.
Is it perhaps

```js
await new Promise((resolve, reject) => setTimeout(resolve, 1000))
```

?

Comment: No - it was just another way of saying: Pull 1 hour of data in each iteration until all data has been fetched (10 iterations / 10 hours in the example).